# Converting XML document to R dataframe where subnodes all have the same name and use childnode for its identification

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing

I'm wanting to convert the following xml document into a dataframe I can use to access the coordinate information.

```
a3 <- xmlParse("test.xml")
```

I figured I will have to do some kind of apply function, but I'm still not certain how to handle xml subnodes with many subnodes that are used to identify that particular node. `<Marker_Data>` and `<Marker>` nodes use a subnode and sister node (respectively) for their unique identification. Is this a straightforward problem? The examples I've seen on stack overflow have unique xml attributes at each level to identify the node: example - [Parsing XML with different number of subnode with same name in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819280/parsing-xml-with-different-number-of-subnode-with-same-name-in-r) or [Extract second attribute of a xml node in R (XML package)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567988/extract-second-attribute-of-a-xml-node-in-r-xml-package)

I would like to make a dataframe like this:

```
| Filename | Type| Xaxis| Yaxis | Zaxis |

| File.tif |  1  | 7172 | 4332  |   1   |

| File.tif |  1  | 7170 | 4140  |   1   |

| File.tif |  2  | 6172 | 4332  |   1   |

| File.tif |  2  | 5173 | 4140  |   1   |
```

test.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CellCounter_Marker_File>
 <Image_Properties>
     <Image_Filename>File.tif</Image_Filename>
 </Image_Properties>
 <Marker_Data>
     <Marker_Type>
         <Type>1</Type>
         <Marker>
             <MarkerX>7172</MarkerX>
             <MarkerY>4332</MarkerY>
             <MarkerZ>1</MarkerZ>
         </Marker>
         <Marker>
             <MarkerX>7170</MarkerX>
             <MarkerY>4140</MarkerY>
             <MarkerZ>1</MarkerZ>
         </Marker>
     </Marker_Type>
     <Marker_Type>
         <Type>2</Type>
         <Marker>
             <MarkerX>6172</MarkerX>
             <MarkerY>4332</MarkerY>
             <MarkerZ>1</MarkerZ>
         </Marker>
         <Marker>
             <MarkerX>5173</MarkerX>
             <MarkerY>4140</MarkerY>
             <MarkerZ>1</MarkerZ>
         </Marker>
     </Marker_Type>
 </Marker_Data>
</CellCounter_Marker_File>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the nodes `Marker` are the ones who are defining your row, you should use them as the basis for looping. Get the `Marker`-nodes using

```
xml_find_all(doc, ".//Marker")
```

You then iterate over the Marker-nodes, and use `xpath` to find  to find it's relevant children (the `MarkerX`, `MarkerY` and `MarkerZ`), but also to find it's sibling (`Type`) and ancestor (`Image_Filename`) nodes... Once found, `xml_text()` is used to extract their values.

**code**

```
library( xml2 )
library( tidyverse )

df <-
  #get all markers, since thay are defining the rows
  xml_find_all(doc, ".//Marker") %>%
  #iterate over the markers, and get relevant data from child-, ancestor- and sibling-nodes
  map_df( function(x) {
    set_names( c( #get the filename, which is in the preceeding sibling 'Type' of the marker 
                  xml_find_all( x, "./ancestor::Marker_Data/preceding-sibling::Image_Properties/Image_Filename") %>% xml_text(),
                  #get the types, whoich are in the preceeding sibling 'Type' of the marker 
                  xml_find_all( x, "./preceding-sibling::Type") %>% xml_text(),
                  #get the MarkersX, Y and Z of the marker 
                  xml_find_all( x, ".//MarkerX") %>% xml_text(),
                  xml_find_all( x, ".//MarkerY") %>% xml_text(),
                  xml_find_all( x, ".//MarkerZ") %>% xml_text() ), 
               #set the column names
               c( "File", "Type", "Xaxis", "Yaxis", "z") ) %>% 
      as.list() %>% #make list
      flatten_df() #flatten to a data.frame
  }) %>%
  type_convert() #let R convert the values for you
```

**output**

```
# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#   File      Type Xaxis Yaxis     z
#   <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 File.tif     1  7172  4332     1
# 2 File.tif     1  7170  4140     1
# 3 File.tif     2  6172  4332     1
# 4 File.tif     2  5173  4140     1
```

**sample data**

```
doc <- read_xml( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CellCounter_Marker_File>
<Image_Properties>
<Image_Filename>File.tif</Image_Filename>
</Image_Properties>
<Marker_Data>
<Marker_Type>
<Type>1</Type>
<Marker>
<MarkerX>7172</MarkerX>
<MarkerY>4332</MarkerY>
<MarkerZ>1</MarkerZ>
</Marker>
<Marker>
<MarkerX>7170</MarkerX>
<MarkerY>4140</MarkerY>
<MarkerZ>1</MarkerZ>
</Marker>
</Marker_Type>
<Marker_Type>
<Type>2</Type>
<Marker>
<MarkerX>6172</MarkerX>
<MarkerY>4332</MarkerY>
<MarkerZ>1</MarkerZ>
</Marker>
<Marker>
<MarkerX>5173</MarkerX>
<MarkerY>4140</MarkerY>
<MarkerZ>1</MarkerZ>
</Marker>
</Marker_Type>
</Marker_Data>
</CellCounter_Marker_File>' )
```

Answer (score 1):

on a well-crafted second SO question!

Since you're using the `XML` package we'll keep you in that universe with this answer:

```
library(XML)

doc <- xmlParse("~/Data/sample.xml")

xpathApply(doc, "//Marker", function(.x) {

  tmp <- xmlToList(.x) # quick way to get the kids into a native R structure

  tmp$Type <- xmlValue(getNodeSet(.x, "../Type")[[1]]) # go back one and get the type

  # go to the root and get the filename (which we can and should do outside the apply)
  xmlValue(
    getNodeSet(.x, "//CellCounter_Marker_File/Image_Properties/Image_Filename")[[1]]
  ) -> tmp$Filename

  # change the names to protect the innocent  
  names(tmp) <- gsub("Marker([[:alpha:]])", "\\1axis", names(tmp))

  tmp

}) -> res

saf <- default.stringsAsFactors()
options("stringsAsFactors" = FALSE) # assuming you want strings vs factors
```

You got lucky with this XML file as the target nodes have consistent kids (well, it's likely more than luck as this looks to be a highly structured file but we'd have to do more work after the `xpathApply()` call if there was a chance there was variation in the child nodes of `<Marker>`):

```
res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, res) 
res <- type.convert(res, as.is = TRUE)
res <- res[,c("Filename", "Type", "Xaxis", "Yaxis", "Zaxis")]
rownames(res) <- NULL

options("stringsAsFactors" = saf)

res
##   Filename Type Xaxis Yaxis Zaxis
## 1 File.tif    1  7172  4332     1
## 2 File.tif    1  7170  4140     1
## 3 File.tif    2  6172  4332     1
## 4 File.tif    2  5173  4140     1

str(res)
## 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  5 variables:
##  $ Filename: chr  "File.tif" "File.tif" "File.tif" "File.tif"
##  $ Type    : int  1 1 2 2
##  $ Xaxis   : int  7172 7170 6172 5173
##  $ Yaxis   : int  4332 4140 4332 4140
##  $ Zaxis   : int  1 1 1 1
```